# Button binding not working which is in Expander, which is in a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

I have a strange issue. I have a listview which contains expander. That expander contains button. When I try to click on it - I am getting an error stating "Cannot find source: Element name".

When I remove CommandParameter from the code and place it again during the runtime - it works. Any ideas why that is happening? All TextBlocks are bind correctly and there are no issue, except for those buttons

Listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="customMeetingsListView"
           Grid.Row="2"
           ItemsSource="{Binding CustomMeetingsList}"
           Style="{StaticResource CtMeetingsListView}"/>
```

List view item template:

```
<Style x:Key="CtMeetingsListView" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Background="Transparent">

                    <Expander.Header>
                    ...
                    </Expander.Header>

                    ...

                    <materialDesign:Badged Grid.Row="0" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                          Badge="{Binding RelatedFiles.Count}"
                          Padding="0 0 8 0">

                      <materialDesign:PopupBox 
                            Background="Transparent"
                            StaysOpen="True">

                         <Button Background="{DynamicResource CardBackground}" 
                                 Margin="0 -8 0 -10"
                                 BorderThickness="0"
                                 Command="{Binding ElementName=customMeetingsListView, Path=DataContext.AddCaseFileCommand}"
                                 CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                          <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="FileDocumentEditOutline" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              Foreground="DarkSlateGray"
                                              Width="12" Height="12"/>
                                          <TextBlock Margin="10 0 0 0" 
                                              Text="Add new" 
                                              Foreground="DarkSlateGray"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               FontSize="10"/>
                                      </StackPanel>
                           </Button>
                      </materialDesign:PopupBox>
                   </materialDesign:Badged>
```

DataContext is bind via Prism:

```
<UserControl
   ...
   xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
   prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
   ...
</UserControl>
```

View model:

```
 private DelegateCommand<CustomMeetingEntity> _addCaseFileCommand = null;
 public DelegateCommand<CustomMeetingEntity> AddCaseFileCommand => _addCaseFileCommand ?? (_addCaseFileCommand = new DelegateCommand<CustomMeetingEntity>(AddCaseFile));
```

Regards,
Eddie

Comment: `customMeetingsListView` may not be a valid name in the scope of the Style. Try to set the DataTemplate directly as `<ListView.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate>...</DataTemplate></ListView.ItemTemplate>`.

Comment: Any template has a namescope of itself. So i don't think elementname can work with any name which isn't in that datatemplate. You can instead use a relativesource binding to search up the visual tree for a listview.